# com.android.support:biometric:28.0.0-alpha03 cannot be resolved

Tags: android, gradle

After using the Jetifier tool in reverse mode I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:biometric:28.0.0-alpha03
```

I didn't found this on any of the Jcenter and MavenCentral repositories.

Should I update the Jetifier rules to map androidx.biometric to something else ?

Thanks,

Comment: [related](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/af27vc/dear_android_team_why_do_you_make_it_so_hard_to/)

Comment: com.android.support:biometric:28.0.0-alpha03 **doesn't exist**

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that
`com.android.support:biometric:28.0.0-alpha03` does not exist, you should use `androidx.biometric:biometric:$biometric_version"` instead where `$biometric_version` is : `1.0.0` according to : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/biometric

The `Alpha03` that does exist is : `Version 1.0.0-alpha03`

Comment: That is true but I cannot target androidx now. It seems that the classes were included in com.android.support:support-compat. Maybe Jetifier should be mapping to this instead of com.android.support.biometric

Comment: Any improvements on this @VitorMagalhães?